# Print character to a certain point on console in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, console

Is there a way to print a character to a certain point on console using Python (3)?
Here's an ideal example on what I'm trying to achieve:

```
def print_char(x, y, char):
    # Move console cursor to 'x', 'y'
    # Set character under cursor to 'char'
```

I know it's possible in some other languages, how about Python? I don't mind if I have to use an external library.

I'm on a Windows 7.

Comment: You'd probably best use something like [urwid](http://urwid.org/).

Comment: What OS? For linux, use curses (in the standard library).

Comment: @sweeneyrod Windows 7 :/

Comment: In that case, the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) suggest either unicurses or the console module as alternatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on UNIX (if you are not, see below), use [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html):

```
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()

def print_char(x, y, char):
    stdscr.addch(y, x, char)
```

Only the Python package for UNIX platforms includes the `curses` module. But don't worry if that doesn't apply to you, as a ported version called [`UniCurses`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/UniCurses) is available for Windows and Mac OS.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm on windows 7 :/

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Then use the ported version that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Yeah didn't see it at first, thanks, I'll give it a try before accepting! :P

Answer (score 3):

If your console/terminal supports ANSI escape characters, then this is a good solution that doesn't require any modules.

```py
def print_char(x, y, char):
    print("\033["+str(y)+";"+str(x)+"H"+char)
```

You may have to translate the coordinates slightly to get it in the correct position, but it works. You can print a string of any length in place of a single character. Also, if you want to execute the function multiple times repeatedly in-between clearing the screen, you may want to do this.

```py
def print_char(x, y, char):
    compstring += "\033["+str(y)+";"+str(x)+"H"+char
```

Then print compstring after all of print_char's have executed. This will reduce flickering from clearing the screen.